# SSIS Version100 database compatibility level is not supported Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm using BIDS that came with SQL Server 2008 R2 (Visual Studio 2008) to design an SSIS package to transfer objects from a SQL Server 2008 R2 Server to another SQL Server using the Transfer SQL Server Objects Task.

The source database has compatibility level 2008 (100).  The destination is SQL Server 2012 with a 2008 compatible database.  When I execute the component though I get the error message:

> SSIS package "Package.dtsx" starting. Information: 0x4002F418 at
>   Transfer SQL Server Objects Task, Transfer SQL Server Objects Task:
>   There are no Logins to transfer. Information: 0x4002F41D at Transfer
>   SQL Server Objects Task, Transfer SQL Server Objects Task: There are
>   no Users to transfer. Error: 0xC002F325 at Transfer SQL Server Objects
>   Task, Transfer SQL Server Objects Task: Execution failed with the
>   following error: "Version100 database compatibility level is not
>   supported.".

I've checked the assembly version of the Transfer SQL Server Objects Task and it is Version 10.  Why am I getting this error message?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can develop a package and run it on the 2008 engine to transfer objects from 2008 to 2012 because even though the destination DB is 2008 compatible, the logins are on an "instance  level" and the instance is 2012.

I suggest that you try to develop an run a package on the 2012 engine and pull the principals from 2008 to 2012

Comment: I thought it would be fine going to 2012 as I'm not transferring any logins, as it specifies in the information messages.  I have just tested transferring from 2008R2 to 2008R2 though and it is working fine so although maybe not directly related to logins seems 2012 is the issue.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Actually, my first test was from a database on the 2008R2 server to another database on that same server.  I have just tested going from 2008R2 to another 2008R2 server and it fails with the same error again.